# fixed point spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

We have the following stationary matrix iteration

$$x_{k+1} = Mx_k + c$$

where $M$ is nxn matrix and $c$ is a vector.

Let $r(M)$ denote the spectral radius of $M$.

Show that spectral 
radius $r(M)$ is infimum over all compatible matrix norms induced by vector norms

Then using this show that

IF
$x^\ast = \lim x_k$ for any $x_0$

then $r(M) < 1$

where $x^\ast$ is the fixed point of the iteration.

Comment: This kind of stuffs are pretty standard. Have you ever looked up any textbook or reference book for a proof?